# How to get rid of the pop up coming up for protractor test while executing in batch?

Tags: javascript, protractor, gulp-protractor

Please go through this image link:

[Image Link for pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Viml4.png)

Whenever i am running the protractor script in batch. This issue is popping up with options. After that another scripts doesn't work.

Here is the error details in console (cmd):

var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnexpectedAlertOpenError: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : if you leave, you will lose your changes.
 Are you sure you want leave?}

What could be the possible reason behind it?

Comment: This is happening because re-navigation is being done in middle of an transaction.Browser is just warning the user with standard msg if you move away in middle you may loose the incomplete information.

Comment: And your code is not expecting/ handling that browser pop-up message.